# Symbol literal or a method

Tags: ruby, symbols, literals

Are `:"foo"` and `:'foo'` notations with quotations a symbol literal, or is `:` a unary operator on a string?

Answer (score 3):

`:` is really just part of the literal you enter yourself or create through a method. Although `:` can take a name or a `"string"` to create a literal, unlike an operator it does not provoke any action or modify a value.

In each case an instance of Symbol is returned. Writing `:` with string notation is sometimes important. If you want to represent, for instance, a string containg whitespace as a symbol you need to use the string notation.

```
> :foo
=> :foo 

> :foo bar
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

> :"foo bar"
=> :"foo bar"
```

Furthermore, it is interesting to explore this with the equality operator `(==)`

```
> :"foo" == :foo
=> true 

> :"foo " == :foo
=> false
```

My advice, do not think of it as passing a string or name to create a symbol, but of different ways to express the same symbol. In the end what you enter is interpreted to an object. This can be achieved in different ways.

```
> :"foo"
=> :foo
```

After all, `%w(foo bar)` is also an alternative way of writing `['foo', 'bar']`.

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby's documentation on Symbol literals](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols) says this:

> You may reference a symbol using a colon: `:my_symbol`.
>
> You may also create symbols by interpolation:
>
> ```
> :"my_symbol1"
> :"my_symbol#{1 + 1}"
> ```

Basically `:"foo"` and `:'foo'` are symbol literals, but they are useful when you want to create symbols using *interpolation*.

Answer (score -1):

You also need quotes if your symbol has spaces:

```
hash = {
  :"a b c" => 10,
  :"x y z" => 20,
}

puts hash[:"a b c"]

--output:--
10
```

So the first one.  From the docs:

> [Symbols] are generated using the :name and :"name" literals syntax, and by
>   the various to_sym methods.